# Typescript: Accessing the properties of a key value pair in typescript

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, key-value

I have a key value pair object in typescript.

`const data = {INTERNAL:[372042],EXTERNAL:[332244]};`

The above is not a map, but I want to iterate over its keys and use it in a switch case pattern.

```
mapData(data: { key: string; value: Array<number> }):void{
switch(data[key]) {
case 'INTERNAL':
      console.log('this is Internal data' =+data[value];
break;
 case 'EXTERNAL':
      console.log('this is External data' =+data[value];
break;
default:
  }
}
```

`data[key]` or `data[value]` is throwing an error saying `key/value is not existing'.`

What is the correct way to access the data.

Comment: You've tagged this question with `for-loop` but there is not `for` loop in the code. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Still not reproducible, since you don't show how you're calling `mapData`. Note that if you're calling `mapData(data)`, it should show a compile error, since `const data = {...}` is not in the correct format for the `data` argument to `mapData`. I think you want `mapData(data: { [key: string]: Array<number> }): void {`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no iteration in the code your provide. Is this what you want to achieve ?

```
for (key in data) {
  mapData({key: key, value: data[key]}); }
```